# bottom navigation menu Проблема с подсветкой значков

Tags: android, android-studio

я новичок. Bottom navigation menu при нажатии реагирует подсвечивает иконку нового окна, но после переходя на следующее activete, продолжает выделятся иконка первого окна

```
 `
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />`
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_time" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_error_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_data" />`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При реализации bottom navigation желательно использовать фрагменты, тогда при переходах у вас нет необходимости в его пересоздании. Когда вы делаете переход на др активити у вас иной инстанс bottom navigation, те он просто ставит его в начальную позицию.

Конечно вы можете победить это, находя каждый раз новый bottomnavigation при переходе и выставляя нужный таб для активити, но лучше так не делать, любая синхронизация излишне если её можно не делать.